# why script and div tag could much in html ,bug html and body tag only one

Tags: javascript

Nice to meet u ,my friend
I had find in baidu.com ,cnds,stack overflow,but cannot get answer.
I have two question "why script and div tag could much in html",other is "why html and body tag only one in html"
Such as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<head>
</head>
<head>
</head>
<head>
</head>

<body></body>
<body></body>
<body></body>
<body></body>

</html>
```

can`t be work

But

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Hello World!")
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Hello World!")
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Hello World!")
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Hello World!")
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Hello World!")
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

can be work

Because in the browsers base code?
Please tell me why ,thank you very much
Your`s friend zt :)

Comment: there can only be one body in your html. Also your second code is invalid but the browser can resolve it for you. Not like your first code. Just check the inspector in dev tools and look at the result

Comment: @Sysix  very thank u you comment ,but i first aim is why script can be multiple，My code is only for reference and does not refer to the actual running state。It can't be said that there must be only one body. Please tell me why it can only be one。Similarly, you can't say that I can have more than one script. I want to know why I can have more than one script

Comment: Who told you you can't have more than one script?

Comment: You can only have one body because the body represents the whole view port of the web page. How are you going to use more than one body?

Comment: @Ricky Mo  nice to meet u ,no body tell me .this is my question ，A question that comes to mind when I read a Book，The book says"<script>console.log("hello")</script><script>document.write('hello')</script>",script and body and head all labels ，but script can be multiple ，head  only one.

Comment: @Ricky Mo  how about head tag

Comment: What are you going to do with multiple <head>? You can put everything that goes within <head> all in one <head>. More than one <head> is meaningless. That's why there is only one <head> in specification.

Comment: You can ask infinitely many questions like "Why it is A but not B?" Are you going to ask every single one you can come up with? Ask yourself does "B" provide any meaningful value in any ways over "A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) (unfortunately [not transcribed into all languages](https://github.com/whatwg/html/wiki/Translations)) might help you out.

Basically an HTML page is structured like a tree.

```
<html>
  <head>
    // ..metadata, CSS, JS
  </head>
  <body>
    // document elements here
  </body>
</html>
```

The main HTML document *can have only one `<head>` and one `<body>` element*.

`<head>` includes meta-data, links to CSS, and often - but not always - links to JS scripts and, depending on the app you're creating, there may be lots of CSS and JS. They maybe links to scripts or CSS you've created, or links to scripts or links online, maybe stored in a open-source CDN.

`<body>` will contain the general markup for the page - all of the elements, the headings, sections, paragraphs etc will be here. It may also contain links to scripts too because sometimes those scripts rely on the document, and its elements, to be loaded first before they can be executed properly.

I suggest trying to read up on [some documentation which has been translated into a few languages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) [and small tutorials](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/) on how to make an HTML page first though. As you learn, you'll start to understand.